# NestJS Angular Universal not loading "index.html" automatically on root path

Tags: nestjs, angular-universal, angular9

I am running an NestJS Angular Universal app on my local server using Angular 9 and Ivy. I can get everything to work when I run:

> npm run serve:ssr

However, nothing loads unless I type the route manually. I would think it would automatically load "index.html" without having to type it in.

> localhost:8080 ----- nothing
>
> localhost:8080/index.html ---- works

Is there a way to modify the code to do a rewrite for the root path? I would think this would not be necessary:

**main.ts**

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = (mainModule && mainModule.filename) || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  bootstrap().catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

Or fix the problem at hand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of working on this, I figured out I had a loop by including a component that was including another component which had a loop in the ts file.  In my case I was subscribing to something I shouldn't have.  I thought this was an IVY / NestJS compatibility problem, but turns out it was my code.